# How much money should the sponsor show to be granted visa to the UK?

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, proof-provenance-of-funds

I'm hoping to apply for the UK visa, but have been holding back because I'm worried I'll get refused (I'm Sri Lankan, refusal rate is high for us!).

I'm a student doing my Master's course in Russia. Almost each summer when I was doing my bachelor's degree (also in Russia) I traveled to many East-Asian countries like China, Japan, Singapore and Thailand.

This year I'd like to visit the UK (in winter because I got an internship during summer).

Since I'm a student, I only have about £450 in my own bank account. My mother will be sponsoring me. She has a fixed account with £5,000 and is hoping to spend £1800 out of it for my trip.

She'll be left with £3200. Her pension plus my father's salary is £300 per month and my father's fixed account deposit is £5000.

(My married sister who earns a £1000 per month takes care of utility bills in the house, because her husband earns more than enough).

I want to know whether they'll think this amount is okay for my mom to get by on after paying for my trip? I get free tickets each year through my sister (she works at an airline).

If they do, then will they accept fixed deposits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There is no fixed amount of money that is considered 'enough' by the UK visa office.**

This is because the amount of money needed varies with many factors. If you are staying in the UK longer you will need more money, but also if you are staying in London hotels, or travelling around by private car, you will need more than if you are staying with a relative who will put you up for free. You should work out how much money you will actually need for the trip, and make sure you have that much available.

Also (and this is very important) **the check on your finances is about more than just 'do you have the right amount of money in your account'**. They will check that you have the money, that it is actually yours, and that it is a reasonable amount of money for you to pay in your circumstances.

So you will need to submit your own accounts, for some time back. If your mother or father is paying towards this trip they will also need to submit all their accounts, not just the 'fixed account' that the money is coming from. They will need to state their incomes and expenses, and show that they amount they are paying is not excessive.

The question also indicates that you or your parents might be considering adding to the account to make it seem like you have more money. **Do not do this.** It's a well-known pattern of deception and will get you refused (even if you were not intending to deceive anyone). If you (or your parents) have had significant deposits to their accounts recently, be sure you explain where it came from (and offer evidence to back that up).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'm planning to stay there for 5 days and to pay about 1800 pounds for the trip...We won't be adding any money to the accounts (except the salary). From what you said, 1800 pounds out of 10000 pounds may be acceptable? I will be sure to add in statements from other accounts as well and to explain where large deposits came from (with proof).  Thanks for your advice!